# Membership.GetUser - table + field

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use:

```
Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name)
```

does anyone know which table and field User.Identity.Name corresponds to when I use the 'standard asp.net membership provider tables' like these:

```
aspnet_Membership
aspnet_Users
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its retrieves record from `aspnet_Membership` table

Please read more about *Stored procedures used by SqlMembershipProvider* section under [Membership Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx) which describes which method access which table.